# How to integrate Pidgin and Evolution into the message indicator?

Tags: indicator, evolution, pidgin, messaging-menu

I upgraded to 12.10, I was using Unity 2d, but as it no longer exists I moved to gnome classic, something in the upgrade seems to have change the message indicator in the "Indicator Applet Complete".

How do I integrate Pidgin and Evolution into the message indicator, there is only a button to launch Pidgin, but a new message does not change the colour of the icon or show up in the dropdown part. Also when minimizing Pidgin it minimizes like a normal window instead of minimizing to the applet. There is nothing in the menu for Evolution at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is likely related to the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-messages/+bug/1040259

In 12.10, the libindicate API was deprecated and a new API was introduced (libmessaging-menu). If you look at the bug page, many applications are in the process of being ported to this new API, including Evolution and Pidgin.

Looks like the Pidgin bug is in progress at least, so we'll have to wait this out.

Answer (score 0):

For Raring this should be fixed. For Quantal you can use Jason Conti's PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/gnome3
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
echo "X-MessagingMenu-UsesChatSection=true" | sudo tee -a /usr/share/applications/pidgin.desktop
```